# Error al ejecutar comando PHP mail()

Tags: php, mail

Tengo una instancia de Windows server 2019 en donde quiero correr un script de PHP para enviar correos electrónicos. He buscado todas las indicaciones para que la conexión SMTP funcione y parece que lo he logrado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He preparado el siguiente código para verificar que la cosa funciona

```
<?php
$from = "jpinilla@XX.XXX.XXX.XX";
$to = "jpinilla@xxx.xxx";
$subject = "Test";
$message = "Un test para verificar si php mail function envía los correos";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
ini_set('SMTP','6aeXXXXXX.XXXXX-server.cloud');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Pero, cuando lo ejecuto desde local, obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error

```
PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;6aexxx.xxxxserver.cloud&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\inetpub\vhosts\default\htdocs\login\test.php on line 13
```

El php.ini dice

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; https://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; https://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

He cambiado los parámetros, poniendo `localhost` en lugar de la url de mi servidor, pero obtengo el mismo resultado. Igual que si pongo o quito los comandos `ini_set()` con las diferentes combinaciones.

En cualquiera de los casos, si lo intento ejecutar en remoto, el navegador me devuelve el error 500

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Saben qué debo hacer para resolverlo?

Comment: Pega el contenido de la línea 13 de test.php al menos para que veamos dónde se produce el error que te indica ;) El error 500 indica un error de programación en muchas ocasiones

Comment: La línea 13 es la que pone `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses PHPmailer

Comment: He editado la pregunta, con más información sobre lo que he intentado.

Comment: Y ese servidor.. tiene configurado a nivel de red que tú puedas atacarle por el puerto 25? Es decir, el firewall puede estar activado y bloqueando, puede haber reglas a nivel de redes para que no puedas atacar al server desde tu ip, o a través de un puerto concreto...

Comment: @VeraCanet El firewall tiene habilitado el puerto 25 tanto de entrada como de salida para cualquier conexión. He supuesto que con eso era suficiente

Comment: No necesitas configurar un smtp server propio para envíos desde PHP. Si la empresa ya tiene un servidor de correos, crea una cuenta para esos propósitos y configura los parámetros en el php.ini. Si el servidor requiere autenticación, mejor usar [phpmailer()](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Recomiendo usar [phpmailer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+phpmailer) en cualquier caso. Es más fácil de configurar y es portable entre plataformas.

Comment: Toma en cuenta las [configuraciones adicionales](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) de `mail()` para Windows.

Comment: Y está seguro que 6aeXXXXXX.XXXXX-server.cloud está escuchando a puerto 25?

Comment: ¿Tu servidor de correo SMTP acepta envíos sin autentificación? De lo contrario, seguramente deberás usar una librería como PHPMailer o PEAR Mail.

Comment: Aunque he tenido muchos problemas para configurarlo, lo he resuelto, como se ha recomendado aquí, usando phpmailer. Combinar Windows server con PHP 8 y librerías como pear o phpmailer es un dolor de cabeza.